# Python 3 getting IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have this python program and I do not know why is throwing the error: "IndexError: list index out of range" when `i` is 1. I am using python 3.10

This is the python code:

```
node_map = [{}]
    for i in range(0,a):
        print(i)
            
        node_map[i]["a_list"] = [j for j in range(number_of_nodes) if mat[i][j] != 0]

        node_map[i]["number_a"] = random.randint(1,number_of_hosts_per_node)
        print(i," ",node_map)
```

I want to have this output:

```
{
  0 : {'a_list': [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8], 'number_a': 1}
  1 : {'a_list': [1, 3], 'number_a': 4}
  ...
}
```

I am noob in python, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Only `node_map[0]` exists. You need to add additional elements to the list (e.g. with `list.append`). Or use use a dict if you want random access insertion

Comment: @Brian61354270 Thank you! Again, I assumed that was happening, but I did not know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to assign a value to an index i that does not exist yet in your node_map list. Initially, node_map only contains one dictionary, so you can access node_map[0], but anything beyond that (node_map[1], node_map[2], etc.) doesn't exist yet.

Here's a possible way to fix this:

```
node_map = [{} for _ in range(a)]
for i in range(a):
    print(i)
        
    node_map[i]["a_list"] = [j for j in range(number_of_nodes) if mat[i][j] != 0]
    node_map[i]["number_a"] = random.randint(1,number_of_hosts_per_node)
    print(i," ",node_map)
```

In this code, we initialize node_map as a list of empty dictionaries of size a (where a is the number of nodes you want to handle).

This way, when you try to access node_map[i] inside the loop, the dictionary at that index will already exist, preventing the IndexError.

But in your desired output, it seems you want each dictionary to be at the index in the dictionary according to the node number. You can use a dictionary of dictionaries for this:

```
node_map = {}
for i in range(a):
    print(i)
        
    node_map[i] = {}
    node_map[i]["a_list"] = [j for j in range(number_of_nodes) if mat[i][j] != 0]
    node_map[i]["number_a"] = random.randint(1,number_of_hosts_per_node)
    print(i," ",node_map)
```

This will create a dictionary node_map that looks like your desired output.

Comment: Thank  you I assumed that is happening but because I am new to python I did not know how to solve it

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT